# How to Construct xml in php with Special Characters?

Tags: php, xml

My user enters message with special characters as follows:

```
this is a test of &amp;&amp;, &amp;&amp;, % as well as '' &quot;&quot;, &quot; instead of this is a test of &, &&, % as well as '' "", "
```

I need to construct XML as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<success>
<message>
this is a test of &amp;, &amp;&amp;, % as well as '' &quot;&quot;, &quot; instead of this is a test of &, &&, % as well as '' "", "
</message>
</success>
```

Can any body help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The xml you present is not well-formed - you can't have an unescaped ampersand in xml if it's not a part of an entity reference (like &amp;).

Comment: More complete & fleshed out answers to this can be found in this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cleansing the input string using `htmlspecialchars()` ([PHP spec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) before adding it to the XML document which should give you the encoding you require.

However if you are not constrained in the way that you create the XML document (i.e. you can do it in a way other than pure string manipulation) I would follow prostynick's solution as it is much more robust in the long term.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() convert half of my string with html entities 
as follows
this is a test of &amp;, &amp;&amp;, % as well as '' &quot;&quot;, &quot; instead of this is a test of &, &&, % as well as ''
But still Some & are not Converted to &amp;,

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DOMDocument` to create xml document and append required elements and text. All characters like `&` will be converted to `&amp;` etc.