# Generating XML document in PHP (escape characters)

Tags: php, xml

I'm generating an XML document from a PHP script and I need to escape the XML special characters.
I know the list of characters that should be escaped; but what is the correct way to do it?

Should the characters be escaped just with backslash (\') or what is the proper way?
Is there any built-in PHP function that can handle this for me?

Comment: @Tchalvak: You are wrong with many of the points you criticize in your bounty description. I tried to make this visible with the existing answers, hope this is helpful.

Comment: I didn't suggest in my answer to use the DOM API just for string escaping. I suggested you generate your whole XML document using that API. This is in response to the problems you mention in your bounty description.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) classes to generate your whole XML document. It will handle encodings and decodings that we don't even want to care about.

---

*Edit:* This was criticized by @Tchalvak:

> The DOM object creates a full XML document, it doesn't easily lend itself to just encoding a string on it's own.

Which is wrong, DOMDocument can properly output just a fragment not the whole document:

```
$doc->saveXML($fragment);
```

which gives:

```
Test &amp; <b> and encode </b> :)
Test &amp;amp; &lt;b&gt; and encode &lt;/b&gt; :)
```

as in:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();

// adding XML verbatim:
$xml = "Test &amp; <b> and encode </b> :)\n";
$fragment->appendXML($xml);

// adding text:
$text = $xml;
$fragment->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($text));

// output the result
echo $doc->saveXML($fragment);
```

See [Demo](http://eval.in/10247)

Comment: According to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31191 you specifically want to use the [createTextNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php) function in order to get proper automatic escaping.

Comment: I think @Tchalvak issue is that its not stream based. That is using DOM will create a bunch of objects. As I mentioned in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15010355/318174) he can use XMLWriter or just port my Java code to PHP that does the proper escaping (Tomas Jancik way is not correct).

Comment: Whoops, http://eval.in/10980 is the correct implementation of a `xmlentities()` function that uses  the native processing.  Probably has some overhead, but then, it's probably worth the peace of mind of using a native/future-proof functionality as well.

Comment: Ugh, it using the dom object doesn't appear to deal with double or single quotes: http://eval.in/11043

Comment: @Kzqai: It does - but just when needed. E.g. for attribute values.

Comment: `return (new DOMDocument())->appendChild(new DOMText($text))->parentNode->saveHTML();`

Comment: @Pete: I ended up using your one-line solution. It works great, except that it encodes things like å=>&aring; and ø=>&oslash; even though they are safe to leave un-encoded. To get around this, I had to specify the characterset, and use saveXml instead of saveHtml. `new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'))->appendChild(new DOMText($value))->parentNode->saveXml()`. PS: I think your comment should probably be its own answer.

Answer (score 38):

I created simple function that escapes with the [five "predefined entities"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent) that are in XML:

```
function xml_entities($string) {
    return strtr(
        $string, 
        array(
            "<" => "&lt;",
            ">" => "&gt;",
            '"' => "&quot;",
            "'" => "&apos;",
            "&" => "&amp;",
        )
    );
}
```

Usage example [Demo](http://eval.in/10248):

```
$text = "Test &amp; <b> and encode </b> :)";
echo xml_entities($text);
```

Output:

```
Test &amp;amp; &lt;b&gt; and encode &lt;/b&gt; :)
```

A similar effect can be achieved by using `str_replace` but it is fragile because of double-replacings (untested, not recommended):

```
function xml_entities($string) {
    return str_replace(
        array("&",     "<",    ">",    '"',      "'"),
        array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;"), 
        $string
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to move the `"&"` and `"&amp;"` array elements to the beginning, or else all the other entities that are created will have their ampersands replaced too. Also, the `strtr` solution doesn't appear to work at all.

Comment: For the OP answering his own question there were really serious flaws in here. I tried to edit it for the good, but I wonder if the original code was used or not ;) - @Nicky De Maeyer: Yes, there are five predefined entities in XML, I placed a link.

Comment: Yes but **attribute escaping** is different than **element escaping** (ie the contents you put in an attribute). [See my Java code for an example](http://code.google.com/p/jatl/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jatl/MarkupUtils.java#109). You don't want to do what @TomasJancik is doing. **Please don't!**. Use a library or do it right.

Answer (score 21):

What about the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function?

```
htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, $encoding);
```

**Note:**  the `ENT_XML1` flag is only available if you have PHP 5.4.0 or higher.

`htmlspecialchars()` with these parameters replaces the following characters:

- `&` (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`
- `"` (double quote) becomes `&quot;`
- `'` (single quote) becomes `&apos;`
- `<` (less than) becomes `&lt;`
- `>` (greater than) becomes `&gt;`

You can get the translation table by using the [`get_html_translation_table()`](http://php.net/get_html_translation_table) function.

Comment: There is no specific need to use `ENT_XML1` for XML compatible encoding - at least for PHP versions 4.3.0 to 5.5.0alpha4. A simple `htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, $encoding);` does the job as well if you can live with a numeric instead of a named entity.

Comment: This is the best way.

Answer (score 15):

Tried hard to deal with XML entity issue, solve in this way:

```
htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: This will only work if those entities are defined in XML, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/

Answer (score 6):

In order to have a valid final XML text, you need to escape all XML entities and have the text written in the same encoding as the XML document processing-instruction states it (the "encoding" in the `<?xml` line). The accented characters don't need to be escaped as long as they are encoded as the document.

However, in many situations simply escaping the input with `htmlspecialchars` may lead to double-encoded entities (for example `&eacute;` would become `&amp;eacute;`), so I suggest decoding html entities first:

```
function xml_escape($s)
{
    $s = html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $s = htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
    return $s;
}
```

Now you need to make sure all accented characters are valid in the XML document encoding. I strongly encourage to always encode XML output in UTF-8, since not all the XML parsers respect the XML document processing-instruction encoding. If your input might come from a different charset, try using `utf8_encode()`.

There's a special case, which is your input may come from one of these encodings: ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8, cp866, cp1251, cp1252, and KOI8-R -- PHP treats them all the same, but there are some slight differences in them -- some of which even `iconv()` cannot handle. I could only solve this encoding issue by complementing `utf8_encode()` behavior:

```
function encode_utf8($s)
{
    $cp1252_map = array(
    "\xc2\x80" => "\xe2\x82\xac",
    "\xc2\x82" => "\xe2\x80\x9a",
    "\xc2\x83" => "\xc6\x92",
    "\xc2\x84" => "\xe2\x80\x9e",
    "\xc2\x85" => "\xe2\x80\xa6",
    "\xc2\x86" => "\xe2\x80\xa0",
    "\xc2\x87" => "\xe2\x80\xa1",
    "\xc2\x88" => "\xcb\x86",
    "\xc2\x89" => "\xe2\x80\xb0",
    "\xc2\x8a" => "\xc5\xa0",
    "\xc2\x8b" => "\xe2\x80\xb9",
    "\xc2\x8c" => "\xc5\x92",
    "\xc2\x8e" => "\xc5\xbd",
    "\xc2\x91" => "\xe2\x80\x98",
    "\xc2\x92" => "\xe2\x80\x99",
    "\xc2\x93" => "\xe2\x80\x9c",
    "\xc2\x94" => "\xe2\x80\x9d",
    "\xc2\x95" => "\xe2\x80\xa2",
    "\xc2\x96" => "\xe2\x80\x93",
    "\xc2\x97" => "\xe2\x80\x94",
    "\xc2\x98" => "\xcb\x9c",
    "\xc2\x99" => "\xe2\x84\xa2",
    "\xc2\x9a" => "\xc5\xa1",
    "\xc2\x9b" => "\xe2\x80\xba",
    "\xc2\x9c" => "\xc5\x93",
    "\xc2\x9e" => "\xc5\xbe",
    "\xc2\x9f" => "\xc5\xb8"
    );
    $s=strtr(utf8_encode($s), $cp1252_map);
    return $s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need proper xml output, simplexml is the way to go:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Answer (score 1):

Proper escaping is the way to get correct XML output but you need to handle escaping **differently** for **attributes** and **elements**. (That is Tomas' answer is incorrect).

I wrote/stole some [Java code](http://code.google.com/p/jatl/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jatl/MarkupUtils.java) a while back that differentiates between attribute and element escaping. The reason is that the XML parser considers all white space special particularly in attributes.

It should be trivial to port that over to PHP (you can use Tomas Jancik's approach with the above appropriate escaping). You don't have to worry about escaping extended entities if your using `UTF-8`.

If you don't want to port my Java code you can look at [**XMLWriter**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) which is stream based and uses libxml so it should be very efficient.

Comment: +1 because I had no idea that XMLWriter did this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methods:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

In that way all entities (html/xml) are escaped and you can put your string inside XML tags

Comment: This is a bad solution, because HTML entities is a larger set than XML entities and most XML parser wont recognize many HTML entities which are not there in XML entities list.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the solution of sadeghj the following code worked for me:

```
/**
 * @param $arr1 the single string that shall be masked
 * @return the resulting string with the masked characters
 */
function replace_char($arr1)
{
    if (strpos ($arr1,'&')!== FALSE) { //test if the character appears 
        $arr1=preg_replace('/&/','&amp;', $arr1); // do this first
    }

    // just encode the
    if (strpos ($arr1,'>')!== FALSE) {
        $arr1=preg_replace('/>/','&gt;', $arr1);
    }
    if (strpos ($arr1,'<')!== FALSE) {
        $arr1=preg_replace('/</','&lt;', $arr1);
    }

    if (strpos ($arr1,'"')!== FALSE) {
        $arr1=preg_replace('/"/','&quot;', $arr1);
    }

    if (strpos ($arr1,'\'')!== FALSE) {
        $arr1=preg_replace('/\'/','&apos;', $arr1);
    }

    return $arr1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 function replace_char($arr1)
 {
  $arr[]=preg_replace('>','&gt', $arr1); 
  $arr[]=preg_replace('<','&lt', $arr1);
  $arr[]=preg_replace('"','&quot', $arr1);
  $arr[]=preg_replace('\'','&apos', $arr1);
  $arr[]=preg_replace('&','&amp', $arr1);

  return $arr;
  }
```

Comment: This is bad on many levels:
**(1)** No need to use regex for a dumb search&replace. **(2)** The replace values are not proper entities (they do not end with a semicolon). **(3)** You will get an array of each replaced version separately. **(4)** This strategy is not even future-proof; or you going to maintain it every time the spec changes?

I have no idea how this got 4 votes.