# Characters intermittently disappearing from PHP-built XML

Tags: php, xml

The XML output from this loop was failing to validate but the validator was giving me different errors each time.  Each time it had to do with the opening < of an element closure being missing.  A different one each time...

[image: xml error 1]

[image: xml error 2]

Every time I refresh and re-validate the output there is at least one of these and it has never yet been in the same member record.

Initially I was adding  tags everywhere which is why you will see many of them wrapping things where they should not be needed.

The XML is built by this loop:

```
if ($members) {
  $xml = '<api><response status="ok"><users>';
  foreach ($members as $m) { 

    $join_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $m->join_date);

    list($md) = $mdObj->retrieve("member_id = '$m->member_id'");
    $join_date = ($m->join_date > 0) ? date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $m->join_date) : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    $address = preg_replace('/\R/', '', $md->m_field_id_3); 
    $xml .= "<user id=\"$m->member_id\"><admin>0</admin><name><![CDATA[$m->username]]></name><company>$md->m_field_id_9</company><company_id>$md->m_field_id_28</company_id><address><![CDATA[$address]]></address><city>$md->m_field_id_5</city><region>$md->m_field_id_6</region><postal_code>$md->m_field_id_7</postal_code><email><![CDATA[$m->email]]></email><phone>$md->m_field_id_10</phone><first>$md->m_field_id_1</first><last>$md->m_field_id_1 $md->m_field_id_2</last><url></url><description><![CDATA[]]></description><status>active</status><date>$join_date</date><modified>0000-00-00 00:00:00</modified></user>";
  }
  $xml .= '</users></response></api>';
  return $xml;
}
```

Has anyone seen this before?  Have any advice?

Here's a little PHP info:

PHP Version 5.2.17

Linux foo.foo.com 2.6.18-274.17.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 4 22:45:44 EST 2012 x86_64

Build Date  Feb 8 2012 14:19:50

Comment: It's better to avoid building xml via string appends.  Use something like simplexml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome's view source routine on a large XML file.  XML obtained from the same source via IE and FireFox was valid across repeated tests.

Additionally Chrome's normal view did not display these aberrations and did not report errors in the XML in normal view.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the database entries you're including into you XML might contain unescaped characters which have special meaning, e.g. `&`, `<`, `>`, `"` and `'` which need to be encoded.

I would also break up that long string into

```
$xml .= "<user id=\"" . $m->member_id . "\"><admin>0</admin><name><![CDATA[";
$xml .= $m->username . "]]></name><company>" . $md->m_field_id_9 . "</company>";
$xml .= "<company_id>" . $md->m_field_id_28 . "</company_id><address><![CDATA[";
$xml .= $address . "]]></address><city>" . $md->m_field_id_5 . "</city><region>";
$xml .= $md->m_field_id_6 . "</region><postal_code>" . $md->m_field_id_7;
$xml .= "</postal_code><email><![CDATA[" . $m->email . "]]></email><phone>";
$xml .= $md->m_field_id_10 . "</phone><first>" . $md->m_field_id_1 . "</first>";
$xml .= "<last>" . $md->m_field_id_1 . $md->m_field_id_2 . "</last><url></url>";
$xml .= "<description><![CDATA[]]></description><status>active</status><date>";
$xml .= $join_date . "</date><modified>0000-00-00 00:00:00</modified></user>";
```

and then use `str_replace()` to specifically encode the above-mentioned characters.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters) with regards to how to escape those characters.

Answer (score 0):

What *could* be happening is that you data contains invisible whitespace, most notably `DEL` characters .. I suppose that would cause this precise behaviour.

To check, loop over each character in the string and print the character code to check if a string contains any hidden whitespace.