# WCF/PHP - XML Parser can't handle HTML entities?

Tags: php, xml, wcf

My RESTful WCF service accepts XML request bodies from clients, most clients are PHP applications.

The PHP applications encode their requests with htmlentities(), which is placed within the element tags. For example, a request to add a new user-account might look like this:

```
$body = "<user>
    <userName>" . htmlentities( $userName ) . "</userName>
</user>"
```

The system works fine, there have been zero errors with it, until today.

I looked through the logs and saw this request had failed:

```
<user>
    <userName>&egrave;eesu</userName>
</user>
```

with the following exceptions:

InvalidOperationException: "There is an error in XML document (4, 12)."
XmlException: "Character reference not valid. Line 4, position 12."

(where line 4, position 12, refers to the `<userName>` element's InnerText (i.e. the string `&egrave;eesu;`).

`&egrave;` is a valid HTML entity, but I understand that XML only defines a minimum set of character references (`&amp;`, `&lt;`, etc), and that XML expects all other characters to be in their document encoding representation instead, and so will reject things like `&egrave;`.

Can someone confirm this is the case? And if so, how can I get PHP to only encode XML-specific entities instead of HTML entities?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use `htmlspecialchars( $userName, ENT_XML1 )` instead, which only converts a minimum of characters to entities without unnecessarily encoding them.

@Jordan's str_replace function does the same thing, however when you benchmark it it's slower because htmlspecialchars is a native function.

Comment: ENT_XML1 is not a valid constant

Comment: @Michelangelo yes it is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php "ENT_XML1 - Handle code as XML 1.".

Comment: right this option is valid only for a particular version of php

Comment: @Michelangelo It's been defined since PHP 5.4.0, released in March 2012 and has existed ever since, saiyng "only for a particular version of PHP" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

XML only has 5 [entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). Parsing into html entities breaks on certain characters because it creates an unencoded & in the entity itself.

Use this function instead of htmlentities() to escape entities:

```
function xmlentities($string) {
return str_replace(array("&", "<", ">", "\"", "'"),
    array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;"), $string);
}
```

Borrowed from Tomas Jancik's anwser to a similar question:
[Generating XML document in PHP (escape characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters)