# Properly Escape & in dynamic PHP to XML script

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I have a dynamically generated XML file that is working great except for the RSS generated is written out as & in the

Sample URL:
http://tinyurl.com/bbhnpg6

Actual Working URL that http://tinyurl.com/crbuny5

How do I properly escape the $URL variable so that it properly writes the &?  Can someone show this sample updated properly please?

```
// selecting data from "mytable"
// mytable = your article table name
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY EntryDate ASC LIMIT 0,5");
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){
// [title] = change it to your article title
$title = $row['MLNumber'];
$link = $row['ListingRid'];
$url = "http://www.domain.com/residential?frame=TAL&amp;MLNO=";
$Unit= $row['Unit'];
$City= $row['City'];
$ZipCode= $row['ZipCode'];
$price = $row['SearchPrice'];
$description = $row['MarketingRemarks'];
$SubdivisionDisplay = $row['SubdivisionDisplay'];

echo '<item>';
echo '<title>' . $Unit . ' ' . $City . ', ' . $ZipCode . ' -' . $SubdivisionDisplay . '</title>';
echo '<link>' . $url . '' . $title . '</link>';
echo '<description><![CDATA[<p><strong>$' . $price . '.00</strong><BR> ' . $description . '<BR> ]]></description>';
//echo '<pubDate>' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", time()) . '</pubDate>';
echo '</item>';
}
echo '</channel>';
echo '</rss>';
?>
```

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters

Comment: No it's not...that is a poorly asked question with no clear answer.  I've provided an exact sample and links to the problem.

Comment: In fact it really _should_ be `&amp;` instead of just `&`. XML should be encoded like that. I also tried to add your feed to Google Reader and when I click the article link it redirects me to the right link (with `&` instead of `&amp;`)

Comment: Related, more generally applicable question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = str_replace('&','&amp;', $url);
```

Comment: If I replace the $url with you suggestion I'll lose the actual URL?  I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: & should be escaped in XMl and encoded with &amp;, who ever is using it will properly read it.