# Passing a javascript variable to a php file that creates XML

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xml

I am new here but use thee forums daily, so please forgive any etiquette errors! My question is actually very similar to this post [Dynamically update variables in external PHP XML generation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944515/dynamically-update-variables-in-external-php-xml-generation-script) . I need to pass a user input from a js var to a php script to query a db to then create an XML. I can get the file to work hardcoded. The ajax call I am using works in that it will pass a var to php using $_get, but it cant seem to output an XML file if I then try to use the passed variable unless it is hardcoded; I have this file working perfeclty in another context with hardcoded sql query. I am not sure if the query is not being passed correctly in the get method or not? maybe the code will help explain my issue a little better.

```
downloadUrl("XML.php"+queryString, function(data){
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    //var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
     var html = "<b>" + type + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon52.png";
    var title = markers[i].getAttribute("address")+ ' Fatalities: ' +markers[i].getAttribute("deaths");
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: point,                         
       icon: icon,
       title: title
      });
     bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                            }
  });//downloadUrl
}//load

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {

  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };
    var type = document.getElementById('confType').value;
    var queryString ="?type=" + type;
  request.open('GET', "XML.php"+queryString, true);
  var params='type='+type;
  request.send(params);
}

function doNothing() {}

<?php
$type = $_GET['type'];
//$type='RiotsProtests';
//$type= mysql_real_escape_string($type);

require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM incident WHERE EVENT_TYPE = `$type`"; //<-------------||||||
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());}

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
header("Content-type: text/xml");
($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("type",$row['EVENT_TYPE']);
$newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['LOCATION']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['LATITUDE']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['LONGITUDE']);
$newnode->setAttribute("deaths", $row['FATALITIES']);
$newnode->setAttribute("actor1", $row['ACTOR1']);
$newnode->setAttribute("actor2", $row['ACTOR2']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

I have tried putting in the queryString, using SESSION_vars, but nothing seems to work. Whenever i call the XML file, it doesnt seem to output anything, like the xml isnt properly getting populated. When i change the header to xml/plain, i get proper output from a hardcode query, but the xml process does not seem to like the variable. please help!!

Comment: Just wondering: is there a specific reason why you're using plain JavaScript instead of jQuery? Also, take care, your SQL query is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://www.bobby-tables.com), and you're using an outdated database API.

Comment: Ah, I'm aware of the SQL injection. I just want to get it to function first. JavaScript is the language I started in and am open to jquery once I learn more of it. Also which API should I be using? I learn by the seat of my pants usually :p

Comment: It's just that jQuery code for AJAX calls is much more simpler than doing it all yourself. When I first started JS, I only used pure JS too, until I discovered jQuery. My opinion is that jQuery is what JavaScript should have been in the first place: simple to understand, portable and _very_ easy to use. For the database API, I personally prefer PDO, but you can go with MySQLi too.