# Standard encoding for urls for Sitemap

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I want to submit my sitemap to Google, but I don't want to mess anything up. I am also having trouble with the URLs to submit; some of them have special characters in them such as the ampersand (`&`) symbol and parenthesis `()`. I just want to know what is the correct way to handle them?

I am currently using PHP's `urlencode()`, which turns them in to `%28`, `%29` and so on which doesn't really look too good and I am scared if I give Google those links and they go on to index them they will index them as

```
domain.com/blabla%28blabla.html
```

Rather than

```
domain.com/blabla&blabla.html
```

Comment: You also might want to merge your two user-profiles, see here for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the XML by hand? Please consider using something like the PHP [DOM classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead.

You'll actually want to encode ampersands as `&amp;`, etc., but it's really best to let a library emit well-formed XML for you.

See [Generating XML document in PHP (escape characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters) for more discussion of this.

Comment: I am using a sitemap.php file which i echo out the XML and getting the links from a database, i am just unsure on how to handle them regarding what they will look like if indexed

Comment: That's what I meant by outputting XML by hand. You're manually creating the XML content.

You can use htmlspecialchars() to get things right almost all of the time.

Comment: Yeah htmlspecialchars is giving me Encoding error most times

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode()` is the right function to use. You definately don't want ampersands in your URL because they are a special character used to form a URL (for passing GET variables).

Comment: So if i give google urls like /someurl_with_&amp_in_it.html, and they go on to index it will they index it like that or as /someurl_with_&_in_it.html