# Export an xml file with php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have data to export in an xml file. For that I use a DOMDocument object with utf-8 encoding.
All special characters are encoded except apostrophe and double quotes.
I want apostrophes and double quotes to be encoded.

Before export :

```
`<p>"don't like"</p>`
```

After export :

```
`&lt;p&gt;"don't like" &lt;/p&gt;`
```

I want it to be like this :

```
`&lt;p&gt; &quot;don&apos;t like&quot; &lt;/p&gt;`
```

PHP Code :

```
$xml_file = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml_file->formatOutput = true;
 ....

$xml_file->save($file_path);
```

Comment: Why does the escaping of apostrophes and quotes matter? It is perfectly valid to have them unescaped like this.

Comment: it is a work obligation

Comment: Check this out for the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters