# Saving '&' to XML Dom Document in PHP

Tags: php, xml

My form post has a title value set as:

```
$title = "Company & Sons";

$xmlDoc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$node = $xmlDoc->createAttribute('title');
$node->value = $title;

...

$completed = $xmlDoc ->saveXML();
```

When I check the saved XML it saves as:

```
<title> Company &amp; Sons </title>
```

How can I save it as it should be `&`?

Comment: It wouldn't be valid XML if it *didn't* do that...

Comment: Try to use &amp; instead.

Comment: that would produce &amp;&amp;

Comment: "Company &amp; Sons" doesn't work?

Comment: It has to do this encoding since `&` is a special character in xml. You will have to unencode it in your XML yourself if your xml reader doesnt. But most will actually decode it just fine.

Comment: Note to commenters: He doesnt have trouble setting the `&`. He was wondering why it will be auto-encoded by DomDocument! So using `&amp;` is not his solution!

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957360/generating-xml-document-in-php-escape-characters)?

Comment: Yeah how can I save it so it remains as & and not encoded like &amp; I don't have an issue with it, it's just a work request.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax here read this, you'll know why does that (escaping)

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try and explain this.

Comment: *"How can I save it as it should be "&"."* - you can save it as plain text and not as XML file for example.

Answer (score 2):

If the `&` character was saved as-is, you would no longer have valid XML.

Because of this, entities with special meanings are escaped in XML; hence the `&amp;`.

To get around this, you can declare your field as `CDATA`:

```
<title>
    <![CDATA[
        Company & Sons
    ]]>
</title>
```

However you do not have to actually worry about the `&amp;` being escaped when deserializing or reading XML. A reader will correctly return escaped values to their original form (much the same way `\u0001` unicode escapes in JSON are turned into a valid character encoding when deserializing).

**tl;dr: your output is fine, don't panic.**