# How to create an XML file with special charaters

Tags: php

How can I create an XML file which uses special characters like À,Æ,Ç,È?

Using SimpleXML, it creates the following error

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 24: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE5 0x6C 0x3A 0x20 in C:\xampp\htdocs\protech\admin\xml and rss\xml_create2.php on line 84
```

Comment: Would you show us the line #24 of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY This...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
utf8_encode($variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `utf8_encode()` should be enough to fix your problem. It will create an UTF-8 encoded string, as the function name already suggests. So when creating your element, use something like

```
new SimpleXMLElement(utf8_encode($xml));
```

Comment: Note that `utf8_encode` will not automagically "create a UTF-8 encoded string as the name suggests" out of anything and everything. It merely converts ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, nothing more. If your input isn't ISO-8859-1, it won't work correctly. The better question to ask is: why isn't the input UTF-8 encoded to begin with?

Comment: true; I shouldn't answer php questions, I really don't know much about it. Your statement about the conversion to UTF-8 is certainly correct. I also agree that the core problem, the non UTF-8 encoding should be addressed - However, as XML person I would also say that often you can not avoid bad formats or encodings, but you have to deal with it. However, in this case it is unclear, as the OP didn't provide enough information.

Comment: utf8_encode() solved my issue that is why i suggested. if there is other way to do it, you can suggest us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOMDocument` to create the xml document and add the elements,text whatever you want ..

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912310/how-to-construct-xml-in-php-with-special-characters) for the reference