# PHP MySQL: How to insert and read from database with clean data

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a MySQL Database with 3 columns (id, question, answer). I used a code to insert with a get method into the database and it worke (sanitized), but im searching for a method in mysqli. And when i want to get from the Database the answer where the questions are matching, i get blank page. 
This is my code used for inserting (it works, but i need mysqli):

```
require 'db.php';

function array_sanitize(&$item) 
{
    $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($item)));
}

function InsertData($register_data) 
{
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data   = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db_question` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}

if ($_GET['code'] == "somecode")
{
    $data = array(
        'question' => $_GET['q']),
        'answer'   => $_GET['a']
    );
    InsertData($data);
    exit();
}
```

And my bigger problem is when im reading the answer by matching the question:

```
require 'db.php';

function sanitize($data) 
{
   return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
}

if ($_GET['code'] == "somecode")
{
    $question = sanitize($_GET['q']);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `answer` FROM `db_question` WHERE `question` = '$question'");
    echo "
    <table id=\"box-table-b\">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope=\"col\">Answer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>";
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['answer'] . "</td>";     
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

I think the question isn't the same with get method, because the questions and the answers too in database contains letters like: ă, î, ș, ț, â 
And with get method the spaces will be replaced with %20, and when i tried getting an answer by id, i get "?" instead of those letters.
If there's someone who can help me.

Even when i've updated my code:

```
$question = sanitize($_GET['q']);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `answer` FROM `tip_question` WHERE `question` = '$question'");
        echo "
        <table id=\"box-table-b\">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope=\"col\">Answer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";
        if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['answer']) . "</td>";        
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</tbody>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

i still ddint get any answer from database. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: [Mastering UTF-8 encoding in PHP and MySQL](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/mastering-unicodeutf-8-encoding-php/)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a question mark back then there is a charset problem. You could try [this](http://www.bluetwanger.de/blog/2006/11/20/mysql-and-utf-8-no-more-question-marks/)

And for changing your code to mysqli check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Answer (score -1):

ă, î, ș, ț are special charters.

so, you are use the utf-8 encode.

also check link: [How to create an XML file with special charaters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011661/how-to-create-an-xml-file-with-special-charaters)

use below code:

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . utf8_encode($row['answer']). "</td>";     
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
    }
```

Comment: but is doing the same thing, i get blank page, it doesn't want to match with the question even if is with utf8 encoded.

Comment: add this code in your connection file $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db("sub_tv",$conn) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8;',$conn);
mysql_query('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=utf8_general_ci;',$conn);
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8;',$db);
mysql_query('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=utf8_general_ci;',$db);
mysql_client_encoding($conn);